# Help locating Serial Port on embedded device

Tags: serial-communication, embedded

I've been slowly working on getting into the workings of a set-top box. I hit a snag when the firmware that it downloads is encrypted. I managed to find some pictures of the circuit board (but haven't opened up my device *yet*) and I have been reading up on communicating over the on-board serial port. I have zero experience with this, other than what I've read on http://devttys0.com and http://jcjc-dev.com/ and various other sites.

So my question is this - Since I'm such a newbie at this, is anyone willing to look at these pictures and help me figure out where a serial port might be hidden?

Pictures @ https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qzd2jpjlv1ieehu/0Am6ttruYe

Any thoughts? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Since asking this question I managed to get into the box via command entry via typing $(command) in a Wifi SSID/password entry location. So thankfully I don't need to find the serial ports (for now). Thanks for your answer, Jonas, I'll happily accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for .1 Inch spaced pads or holes, at least three contacts will be in a row (as you need RX, TX and GND). At a glance I can't find a port in the photos. You should try to get some really high resolution top and bottom pictures.